# Large arrays raises erroneous memory access ada

Tags: ada

Is there a way to get this code working? I want to create an array with the size of 10mio. addresses. But running this code raises a *CONSTRAINT_ERROR : erroneous memory access*.

```
procedure Main is
   type A_Type is abstract tagged null record;

   type B_Type is new A_Type with null record;
   type B_Type_Access is access all B_Type;

   type C is array (1 .. 10_000_000) of B_Type_Access;
   D : C;
begin
   null;
end Main;
```

Comment: Using GNAT, it’s a good idea to build with `-fstack-check`. Doing this with your code results (on Mac OS X) in a `Storage_Error` with message `stack overflow`.

Comment: On Linux, the limit for an executable's main stack size is 8 MB if you didn't change it. Other operating systems likely have similar limits. An array of 10 million address needs about 40 MB on 32 bit and 80 MB on 64 bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess the creation of variable D in the stack is too much. Try creating an array of access variables in a pool like so:

```
PROCEDURE Main IS
   TYPE A_Type IS ABSTRACT TAGGED NULL RECORD;

   TYPE B_Type IS NEW A_Type WITH NULL RECORD;
   TYPE B_Type_Access IS ACCESS ALL B_Type;

   TYPE C IS ARRAY (1 .. 10_000_000) OF B_Type_Access;
   TYPE E IS ACCESS C;
   D : E;
BEGIN
   D := NEW C;


END Main;
```

Comment: I cannot use this tip, if it is an unconstrained array, or? I tried it, but did not have success. EDIT: I can. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Herr_Doktor had one good solution.  Another is to put the array (and all the types) in a package (I assume that `Main` will not call itself recursively):

```
package Main_Package is
    procedure Main;
end Main_Package;

package body Main_Package is

    type A_Type is abstract tagged null record;

    type B_Type is new A_Type with null record;
    type B_Type_Access is access all B_Type;

    type C is array (1 .. 10_000_000) of B_Type_Access;
    D : C;

    procedure Main is
    begin
        -- whatever you were going to do
    end Main;

end Main_Package;

with Main_Package;
procedure Main is
begin
    Main_Package.Main;
end Main;
```

Now, since the array `C` is no longer inside a procedure, it will be allocated in regular data memory instead of on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Ada are **typically** allocated on the stack.  This means that you have to assure that your process is allowed to have a sufficiently large stack for the variables you declare.

On a Linux system you can use the `ulimit` command to change how large a stack processes will get:

```
% cat main.adb
procedure Main is
   type A_Type is abstract tagged null record;

   type B_Type is new A_Type with null record;
   type B_Type_Access is access all B_Type;

   type C is array (1 .. 10_000_000) of B_Type_Access;
   D : C;
begin
   null;
end Main;
% gnatmake -gnato -gnata -fstack-check main.adb
[...]
```

Running it with enough stack space:

```
% ulimit -s 90000
% ./main
% echo $?
0
```

Running it with too litle stack space:

```
% ulimit -s 9000
% ./main

raised STORAGE_ERROR : stack overflow (or erroneous memory access)
% echo $?
1
```